# Inner bounds of polygon in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, mapbox, leaflet

How can I find the inner bounds of a polygon in Leaflet? I a want to plot points randomly in polygon but when I say

```
Layer.getBounds()
```

I get the bounds and I can still plot the markers approximately with in the saure i draw except most of them fall far out the intended polygons. This is because, `getBounds()` gives me out bounds.

Does any one have an idea how I can get inner bounds of a polygon?

Comment: There isn't really a concept of an "inner bounds".  Bounds are the maximum and minimum x and y (or lat and lon, x being lon) the polygon touches.

Comment: Okay. So i can't possibly draw a square inside the polygon. Does this mean what i have is as close as am going to get to plotting random markers with in a district?

Comment: You could use getLatLngs to get the vertices, generate points within the bounds, and use the even-odd rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule to determine whether your points are inside the polygon.  It would take a bit of scripting.

Comment: following up on what @RussellatISC said, you could use something like [Leaflet point in polygon](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) in conjunction with getBounds(), to find points that only fall within the polygon.

Comment: Thanks @Russell and toms ... I should now be able to make my point more accurate.  I will post my findings when I Finnaly get it plot accurately.

Answer (score 3):

Mapbox has a pointinpolygon you could use.  https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip
Layer must be: L.geoJSON layer

Then use something like :

```
var sw = polygon.getBounds().getSouthWest();
var ne = polygon.getBounds().getNorthEast();


for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var randomLat = Math.random() * (ne.lat() - sw.lat()) +sw.lat();
  var randomLng = Math.random() * (ne.lng() - sw.lng()) +sw.lng();
  var p = new L.latlng(randomLat, randomLng);
  if (leafletPip.pointInLayer(p, polygon)) {
    var mark = new L.marker(p).addTo(map);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This  can work, but the problem is that the random point is generated with a square box vs the actual polygon, so if the point is inside the bounding box, but outside the polygon itself, you'll need to call your function (in the example above, a loop) again until a match (pip) is found

Answer (score 0):

I have done with below code:

```
function getPolygonBounds() {
    var polygons = []
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Polygon && !(layer instanceof L.Rectangle)) {
            polygons.push(layer.getLatLngs()) //Returns an array of arrays of geographical points in each polygon.
            polygons.push(layer.getBounds()) //Returns a GeoJSON representation of the polygon (GeoJSON Polygon Feature).
        }
    })
    return polygons
}
```